# Setup hide / unhide GameOjbect in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, show-hide, gameobject

I'm trying to setup a simple hide and unhide gameobject in Unity, but can't seem to get my coding to work correctly.  What wrong with what I have written so far.

```
#pragma strict

public var myObject :GameObject;

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(1120,930,100,50),"3D MODEL"))

    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);

    }


}
```

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ will maybe be a better place to ask (also check out http://answers.unity3d.com, the community here is fast and maybe know more about Unity3D than people from SO) ! Anyway, your code here is just to unhide the gameobject, right ?

Answer (score 3):

There you go, this should solve your problem.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7776/how-to-make-an-gameobject-invisible-and-disappeare.html
Good luck.

> You can **turn off the rendering** of a GameObject by disabling its MeshRenderer component, e.g.

```
GetComponent(MeshRenderer).enabled = false;
```

> You can **disable** a GameObject entirely by making it inactive, 
>   e.g.

```
gameObject.active = false;
```

Comment: Don't only put the link, also post the code from that post ! If the post dissapear, the link will be unavailable !

Comment: No problem, I've been doing this alot, got flagged and stuff.. Learning the hard way ah ah ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of SetActive :

```
renderer.enabled = true; (to show the game object)

renderer.enabled = false; (to hide the game object)
```

---

If the gameobject got children in it, this piece of code might help :

```
function Hide() {
    if (#condition#) {
        ToggleVisibility();
    }
}

function ToggleVisibility() {
    // toggles the visibility of this gameobject and all it's children
    var renderers = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.();
    for (var r : Renderer in renderers) {
        r.enabled = !r.enabled;
    }
}
```

( second code coming from : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14165/show-and-hide-a-prefab-or-gameobject.html)

Comment: Yes, the gameobject does have children in it.  maybe that the reason i can't hide and unhide gameobject.  I can see the mesh renderer check box  turn off, but mesh doesn't reappear.

Comment: Do you just want to hide the object or really set it inactive ? Those are not the same thing - Did the code I gave you worked ?

Comment: I just wanted to hide and unhide gameobject.  That it.

Answer (score 0):

A `GameObject` is not running scripts once it is set un-active. Which inherently means it cannot run a script to set itself active again. an outside source must be what sets it active again.